# How to convert Varchar "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" to Datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert / cast a `varchar` column which has values stored in  `YYYYMMDD HHMMSS` format to `datetime` datatype.

[image]

I tried using the following SQL statement, but I was not able to get the exact results.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(event_time, 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0,  ':'), 15, 0, ':')) ConvertedDate 
FROM
    table1
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it already has a space between the date and time, so you don't need to add one:

```
select convert(datetime, stuff(stuff('20151005 114450', 12, 0,  ':'), 15, 0, ':'))
```

Comment: Good catch. Like yours better than mine. :)